# Interactive Graphics with PixiJS - mouseover doesn't fire, while click does

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

Trying to fire events when hovering over Graphics element.
click event works as expected, but mouseover does not seem to fire.

Here's excerpt with fiddlejs link:

```
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(500, 500, null, true);
var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0xFFFFFF);
stage.interactive = true;

document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(renderer.view);

var rect = new PIXI.Graphics();
rect.lineStyle(1, 0x000);

rect.interactive = true;
rect.hitArea = new PIXI.Rectangle(0,0, 200, 200);
rect.drawRect(0,0, 200,200);
rect.click = function(ev) { console.log("clicked"); }
rect.mouseover = function(ev) { console.log("over"); }
stage.addChild(rect);

renderer.render(stage);
```

FiddleJS link:
http://jsfiddle.net/anps0abt/

Maybe I should use sprites instead of Graphics elements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PIXI.InteractionManager handles mouseover and mouseout events in its update() function. You need to continuously update the renderer each frame in order to get a response from those events

```
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(500, 500, null, true);
var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0xFFFFFF);
stage.interactive = true;

document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(renderer.view);

var rect = new PIXI.Graphics();
rect.lineStyle(1, 0x000);

rect.interactive = true;
rect.hitArea = new PIXI.Rectangle(0,0, 200, 200);
rect.drawRect(0,0, 200,200);
rect.click = function(ev) { console.log("clicked"); }
rect.mouseover = function(ev) { console.log("over"); }
stage.addChild(rect);

update();
function update(){
    requestAnimFrame(update);
    renderer.render(stage);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/anps0abt/3/

Comment: it seems that it has changed after some years